# Deleting list Item in react keep older items instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to delete selected item from list.

When I click on delete the right item get deleted from the list content but on UI I get always the list item fired.

I seems to keep track of JSX `keys` and show last values.

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-ui-example-forked-l6yf2?file=/example.js)

```
const Holidays = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  const [state, setState] = useState({ ...props });
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(props);
    console.log(state);
  }, []);
  const addNewHoliday = () => {
    const obj = { start: "12/12", end: "12/13" };
    setState(update(state, { daysOffList: { $push: [obj] } }));
  };
  const deleteHoliday = (i) => {
    const objects = state.daysOffList.filter((elm, index) => index != i);

    console.log({ objects });
    setState(update(state, { daysOffList: { $set: objects } }));
    console.log(state.daysOffList);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Header as="h1" content="Select Holidays" />
      <Button
        primary
        icon={<AddIcon />}
        text
        content="Add new holidays"
        onClick={() => addNewHoliday(state)}
      />

      {state?.daysOffList?.map((elm, i) => {
        console.log(elm.end);
        return (
          <Flex key={i.toString()} gap="gap.small">
            <>
              <Header as="h5" content="Start Date" />
              <Datepicker
                defaultSelectedDate={
                  new Date(`${elm.start}/${new Date().getFullYear()}`)
                }
              />
            </>
            <>
              <Header as="h5" content="End Date" />
              <Datepicker
                defaultSelectedDate={
                  new Date(`${elm.end}/${new Date().getFullYear()}`)
                }
              />
            </>
            <Button
              key={i.toString()}
              primary
              icon={<TrashCanIcon />}
              text
              onClick={() => deleteHoliday(i)}
            />
            <span>{JSON.stringify(state.daysOffList)}</span>
          </Flex>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
export default Holidays;
```

[image]

**Update**

I'm trying to make a uniq id by adding timeStamp.

```
    return (
      <Flex key={`${JSON.stringify(elm)} ${Date.now()}`} gap="gap.small">
        <>
          <Header as="h5" content="Start Date" />
          <Datepicker
            defaultSelectedDate={
              new Date(`${elm.start}/${new Date().getFullYear()}`)
            }
          />
        </>
        <>
          <Header as="h5" content="End Date" />
          <Datepicker
            defaultSelectedDate={
              new Date(`${elm.end}/${new Date().getFullYear()}`)
            }
          />
        </>
        <Button
          primary
          key={`${JSON.stringify(elm)} ${Date.now()}`}
          icon={<TrashCanIcon />}
          text
          onClick={() => deleteHoliday(i)}
        />{" "}
      </Flex>
    );
```

I was hoping that the error disappear but still getting same behaviour

Comment: The problem is you're using the index in the array as the key. This is [not the correct approach](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: what are you saying about the older items, you are meanig you dont need to the jsx to render again? i cannot get the idea, can you explain with more details? plz :)

Comment: To confirm what @PatrickRoberts says, if you change to `key={JSON.stringify(elm)}` you'll find that the correct item gets deleted. However that's really not a good long-term solution for a "key"

Comment: What I mean is that if I have A, B , C, and I delete B, is my data it will get A,C but in UI it will shows A,B, If I delete A, in data B,C in UI A,B again

Comment: Right, because you are using the array index as the React key ***and*** mutating the underlying data, indices 0 and 1 still exist and didn't change so react bails on rerendering the JSX associated with these keys. Choose a react key that is intrinsic/unique to the data you are mapping. If your data doesn't have this quality then augment your data with a GUID property to use for this purpose.

Comment: Adding to everyone else, the React docs explain this issue: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: I have updated my code by adding timestamp ( I still filter on array index ), but I still have the same behaviour, I thought that the item will be unique now.
You can see my data structure in demo ( when setting state variable )

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are using the array index as the React key ***and*** you are mutating the underlying data array. When you click the second entry to delete it, the third element shifts forward to fill the gap and is now assigned the React key for the element just removed. React uses the key to help in reconciliation, if the key remains stable React bails on rerendering the UI.

You also can't console log state immediately ***after*** an enqueued state update and expect to see the updated state.

```
setState(update(state, { daysOffList: { $set: objects } }));
console.log(state.daysOffList);
```

React state updates are asynchronous and processed ***between*** render cycles. The above can, and will, only ever log the state value from the ***current*** render cycle, not the update enqueued for the ***next*** render cycle.

## Solution

Use a GUID for each start/end data object. [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) is a fantastic package for this and has really good uniqueness guarantees and is incredibly simple to use.

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

// generate unique id
uuidV4();
```

To specifically address the issues in your code:

- Add `id` properties to your data

  ```
   const daysOffList = [
     { id: uuidV4(), start: "12/12", end: "12/15" },
     { id: uuidV4(), start: "12/12", end: "12/17" },
     { id: uuidV4(), start: "12/12", end: "12/19" }
   ];

   ...

   const addNewHoliday = () => {
     const obj = {
       id: uuidV4(),
       start: "12/12",
       end: "12/13",
     };
     setState(update(state, { daysOffList: { $push: [obj] } }));
   };
  ```
- Update handler to consume id to delete

  ```
   const deleteHoliday = (id) => {
     const objects = state.daysOffList.filter((elm) => elm.id !== id);
     setState(update(state, { daysOffList: { $set: objects } }));
   };
  ```
- Use the element id property as the React key

  ```
   {state.daysOffList?.map((elm, i) => {
     return (
       <Flex key={elm.id} gap="gap.small">
         ...
       </Flex>
     );
   })}
  ```
- Pass the element id to the delete handler

  ```
   <Button
     primary
     icon={<TrashCanIcon />}
     text
     onClick={() => deleteHoliday(elm.id)}
   />
  ```
- Use an `useEffect` React hook to log any state update

  ```
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log(state.daysOffList);
   }, [state.daysOffList]);
  ```

## Demo

[image: Edit deleting-list-item-in-react-keep-older-items-instead]

**Note:** If you don't want (or can't) install additional 3rd-party dependencies then you can roll your own id generator. This will work in a pinch but you should really go for a real proven solution.

```
const genId = ((seed = 0) => () => seed++)();
genId(); // 0
genId(); // 1
```